# Error while converting CER into PEM file in push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I am following ablove link to enable push notification for my app.It gives error when i convert cer file into pem file

```
system17:~ sairam$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

Error opening Certificate aps_development.cer
2383:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.2/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('aps_development.cer','r')
2383:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.2/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load certificate
```

any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: That probably means that the file aps_development.cer does not exist in the current directory.

Comment: i have that file in desktop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You call the "openssl" command from your home directory, but the certificate file is in
your Desktop directory. So you have to change to that directory first:

```
$ cd Desktop
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for `-inform der` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ openssl pkcs12 -in WenderCastPush.p12 -out WenderCastPush.pem -nodes -clcerts
```